# Heapify vs Heap-Sort vs Construct Heap

Tags: arrays, sorting, data-structures, binary-tree, heap

I am learning the heap data structure and am very confused between the heap functions mentioned in the title.

According to my understanding , the algorithm for max heapify looks very similar to constructing a heap using a top-down approach . Even heap sort is similar to a top down construction of a heap with the extra step of pushing the first element to the end of the array at each iteration.

Also , I would like to know if in these functions , are we working on an actual binary tree or an array? Or are we just representing a binary tree using an array and just re-arranging it's elements?

Comment: Could you focus on only one question? Currently your question is too broad. For instance, only ask about comparison between two functions, not three, and exclude the questions in your last paragraph. Instead add the literal code you are looking at and pinpoint more exactly what the problem is you see.

Answer (score 3):

**Definition of Heap** : Heap is a Complete Binary Tree, which satisfy the property that parent node value is larger than child nodes' (in case of MAX-HEAP) or smaller (in case of MIN-HEAP). This property of Heap has to be followed by each node with it's child nodes at each level of tree.

**Storage in memory :** Binary Tree is being stored in memory in form of array as data structure, following level traversal to order elements such that, for each index i as parent, children would be 2*i+1 and 2*i+2

**Heapify(Construct Heap)** is an approach (either top-down or bottom-up), which arranges elements in any array such that, when checked for any index i as parent, its child nodes values at index 2*i+1 and 2*i+2 would follow either MAX-HEAP or MIN-HEAP property.
It doesn't sort array in ascending or descending order.

**Heap-Sort :** Sort array in ascending or descending order.
As name suggests, we are using Heap BT property here to rearrange array elements.
Heap Sort is an application of Heap BT.

**Steps to sort an input array via Heap-Sort:**

1. Arrange array elements in order as of MAX-HEAP or MIN-HEAP, using Heapify(Construct Heap) logic.
   (Logically it will follow Heap BT property, but storage wise it is still an array)
2. Put a loop over array, start from root node, compare it with last leaf node, swap if required and delete leaf node.
   Insert deleted element in a different array.
   Follow this until all nodes are deleted.
   Now, when we delete any node in Heap, we need to do Heapify residual array as part of delete operation on Heap BT.
   And the deleted elements while insertion in array follows order as ascending (MIN-HEAP) or descending (MAX-HEAP).
   This is similar to selection sort, which on comparison in each pass, places max/min element to final position and gets excluded in comparison in next pass.

Answer (score 1):

PriorityQueue is an Abstract Data type where each element has a priority associated with it. Many data structures implement PriorityQueue. Heap is one of those. We can use them as per our needs. Min-Heap gives high priority to the least element and Max-Heap gives high priority to the greatest element.

> Also , I would like to know if in these functions , are we working on
> an actual binary tree or an array? Or are we just representing a
> binary tree using an array and just re-arranging it's elements?

Heap is based on the binary tree structure and can be ***easily implemented using Arrays***. You can also use an actual binary tree to implement this.

***Heapify*** is an operation that is involved when inserting or removing an element into the Heap. When we insert an element into the Heap, we insert it at the end of the array and do ***HeapifyUp*** which bubbles up the inserted element to the correct position. when removing an element from the top (beginning), we take the last element from the array and insert it in the beginning, and bubble down (***HeapifyDown***) the element until it gets to the correct position.

[This](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Emcw/cs367/lectures/heaps.html) is a nice article to read.